# What are the difference between open loop and closed hydraulic system?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, hydraulics

I'm trying to get informative resource material through this.

Comment: Coudl you read through https://www.crossco.com/blog/closed-loop-vs-open-loop-hydraulic-systems, and then make your question more specific?

Comment: Check this out : https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 1):

One discards the depressurized hydraulic fluid, the other recirculates it back to the pump. That's all there is to it.

For example, the Falcon 9 rocket first stage uses open loop, using pressurized nitrogen to pressurize the hydraulic fluid to control the grid fins, then directs the depressurized fluid that leaves the actuators into the fuel tank and uses it as fuel during landing.

Answer (score 1):

In closed loop hydraulic system motor return is connected directly to the hydraulic pump inlet and in open loop  the hydraulic pump inlet and the motor are connected to the reservoir. If you are interested to find more details on this, check: [Types of hydraulic system](https://whyps.com/types-of-hydraulic-system)